# How can I access a gradle.properties variables using the new Gradle Kotlin DSL

Tags: android, kotlin, maven, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have to use these credentials to access a maven repo in my `gradle.properties`:

```
repositoryUsername=user_name_placeholder
repositoryIdentityToken=identity_token_placeholder
```

Then, I need to use them in the `setting.gradle.kts` file like this:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            credentials {
                username = repositoryUsername
                password = repositoryIdentityToken
            }
            url = uri("https://some-repository/artifactory/maven")
        }
    }
}
```

But that is not working, how does it work using the new Gradle Kotlin DSL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use variables in your `gradle.properties` like the ones you are asking:

```
repositoryUsername=user_name_placeholder
repositoryIdentityToken=identity_token_placeholder
```

This is the code that you need to write in your `setting.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            credentials {
                username = providers.gradleProperty("repositoryUsername").get()
                password = providers.gradleProperty("repositoryIdentityToken").get()
            }
            url = uri("https://repositories.tomtom.com/artifactory/maven")
        }
    }
}
```

I've found the information in the official `gradle` documentation
`example 1` and `example 2`:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html

Comment: Note the docs also show `val propertyName: String by project` (or `by settings` if in the settings file) is a possibility as well, just in case someone prefers that.